# Importing selective data using impdp

Tags: oracle, import, impdp

I have an entire DB to be imported as a dump into my own. I want to exclude data out of certain tables(mostly because they are huge in size and not useful). I cannot entirely exclude those tables since I need the table object per se(minus the data) and will have to re create them in  my schema if I do so. Also in the absence of those table objects , various other foreign constraints defined on other tables will also fail to be imported and will need to be redefined.So I need to exclude just the data from certain tables.I want data from all other tables though.

Is there a set of parameters for impdp that can help me do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely make 2 runs.  One to create all the table objects, but instead of using tables in the second impdp run, use the exclude

```
impdp ... Content=data_only exclude=TABLE:"IN ('table1', 'table2')"
```

The other way works, but this way you only have to list the tables you don't want versus all that you want.

Comment: For some reason `exclude=TABLE:"IN ('table1', 'table2')"` didn't work for me in 11.4. I had to write: `exclude=TABLE:"IN ('table1')" exclude=TABLE:"IN ('table2')"` separately for each table

Answer (score 10):

I would make two runs at it: The first I would import metadata only:

`impdp ... CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY`

The second would include the data only for the tables I was interested in:

`impdp ... CONTENT=DATA_ONLY TABLES=table1,table2...`

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

```
EXCLUDE=[object_type]:[name_clause],[object_type]:[name_clause]
INCLUDE=[object_type]:[name_clause],[object_type]:[name_clause]
```

Examples of operator-usage:

```
   EXCLUDE=SEQUENCE
or EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('EMP','DEPT')"
or EXCLUDE=INDEX:"= 'MY_INDX'"
or INCLUDE=PROCEDURE:"LIKE 'MY_PROC_%'"
or INCLUDE=TABLE:"> 'E'"
```

The parameter can also be stored in a parameter file, for example: `exp.par`

```
DIRECTORY = my_dir
DUMPFILE = exp_tab.dmp
LOGFILE = exp_tab.log
SCHEMAS = scott
INCLUDE = TABLE:"IN ('EMP', 'DEPT')"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the table is big for export import the you can use "SAMPLE" parameter in expdp command to take export of table for what ever percentage you want ....

```
$ expdp tables=T100test DIRECTORY=expimp1 DUMPFILE=test12.dmp SAMPLE = 10;
```

This command will export only 10% data of the T100test table's data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can exclude directly when importing using impdp query parameter

```
impdp [...] QUERY='TABLE_NAME:"WHERE rownum = 0"'
```

cf : [community.oracle.com](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2336851)